# Is there any way to disable Entity Proxies in Fluent API?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I know that we can disable ProxyCreationEnabled programmatically in this way:

```
 using (var newContext = new MyDbContext())
        {
           newContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

        }
```

but i want to know is there any way to disable Entity Proxies in Fluent API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FluentAPI` is about **mapping** configuration, and Proxy creation is about context configuration.

You can try to:

1. Simply add `this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;` to the constructor.
2. 'Seal' your Entities using `sealed class`.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592886.aspx)